# Jhipster with uaa application with session scope bean

Tags: spring-boot, jhipster

I have generated jhipster application with uaa. Now when I use session scope spring  bean configuration i got error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
```

Comment: Can you please include some code to reproduce the error?